# How do logicians think about Hegel's logic

Tags: logic, hegel, dialectic

I was told, a while ago now, that if I wanted to study Hegel, even Hegelian Marxism, I'd be best off studying his logic first.

Having recently asked this [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54786/what-paraconsistent-logics-are-there) I was wondering how do contemporary logicians formalize Hegelian logic using the terminology and symbolism of modern formal logic?

Comment: Do you mean, how do contemporary logicians feel, personally or otherwise, about Hegelian logic? Or do you mean, how do contemporary logicians formalize Hegelian logic using the terminology and symbolism of modern formal logic? Because, the phrase "How do logicians think about Hegel's logic" sounds like you're asking for people's general opinions on Hegel and his logic, but "Does it e.g. replace LNC (law of non-contradiction) with new assumptions?" sounds like you're asking a more technical question of how Hegelian logic is formalized, and both of those are different questions.

Comment: @Not_Here why not both?

Comment: Well, if you're asking both it's probably better to explicitly state that you're asking two questions (it's in the rules that you're supposed to only ask one question on the site). But I think more importantly, the first question isn't a question about philosophy, and I feel like if that was as deep as your question got ("what do people think about x?"), it would be closed as either too subjective or not about philosophy, but a question about the formalization of Hegelian logic is actually on topic and a question about philosophy. So, it very much changes the quality of your question.

Comment: Either way, if you are asking both, your question is vague because it's not clear that you're asking two questions, it looks like you're asking one question and it's indeterminate which one of two slightly related questions you're asking. Again, I think it's in the best interest for the quality of your question and how it will be received if you make it explicit what you actually mean; that's what I am trying to point out.

Comment: ok but no sarcastic comments about e.g. logicians not taking hegel's "logic" seriously @Not_Here

Comment: I am not sure what that comment is supposed to mean, if somebody is giving you a sarcastic response then you can flag it as inappropriate or not a real answer and the mods will take care of it. None of what I said was a sarcastic remark about logicians and Hegel. It kind of looks like you just admitted that your question was vague on purpose to not get sarcastic responses, though, which seems like a bad way to ask a question.

Comment: hey no i didn't mean you were being sarcastic at all :) @Not_Here

Comment: "To know what a thing really is, we have to get beyond its immediately given state (S is S) and follow out the process in which it turns into something other than itself (P). In the process of becoming P, however, S still remains S. ... truth of a world permeated by negativity." Marcuse, Reason and Revolution, Internet Archive.

Comment: What logic can do this?  Perhaps something can be done, there are so many flavors, I have no idea. But logic is often a snapshot, and the world moves, only the foolish cling to the given. The given is the bourgeois understanding. By the way, of the modern Marxists, Marcuse was far and away the best Hegel scholar. His attempted Dissertation under Heidegger was on Hegel.

Comment: Aufheben https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufheben

Comment: I didn't say Hegel didn't use propositions; I said his logic was essentially a set of relationships of adequacy between concepts. My answer has plainly conveyed nothing and I have deleted it accordingly.

Comment: no i didn't mean he didn't "use" propositions, only that it has some as assumptions or something very like assumptions @GeoffreyThomas no worries, sorry if i'm a pain

Comment: @user3293056. Okay, thanks, point taken. I have left my upvote because I still think you have put a good question. I have added to my answer. Perhaps the new material will help. Welcome to PSE btw - Best : Geoffrey

Answer (score 6):

In a very compressed nutshell, modern logic is concerned with relations of implication, contradiction, independence and the like between propositions and predicates.

In contrast Hegel's logic operates not on propositions or predicates but on 'notions', *Begriffe*, or (roughly) concepts. On his account certain concepts are more adequate to the nature or expression of reality than others. The concept of determinate being, for example, is more adequate to, more informative about, reality than the mere concept of being; and being, distinguished as finite or infinite, is more adequate than merely determinate being.

He moves up through concepts - very many more than these - until he teaches absolute being, the whole of reality or the Absolute, than which no other concept can be more adequate to reality.

So Hegel is not doing badly something that later logicians are doing better; he is doing something different. This isn't to say that he does not use propositions or predicates to formulate his logic but his logic is not about them. Nor is it to say that his logic is without internal faults. Not all the rungs of Hegel's ladder are secure.

To stress the contrast from a different angle ...

What modern logicians are concerned to formalise are, to repeat, relations of implication, contradiction, independence and the like between propositions and predicates. Hegel's logic of concepts is off-beam from this concern, answerable as it is to the admittedly unusual idea of adequacy to reality - for which, moreover, Hegel has his own criteria. There is also the problem that it is hard to disentangle Hegel's logic of concepts from his metaphysics and epistemology. Unlike modern logicians, Hegel connected logic explicitly with metaphysics and epistemology. All three are interwoven in his philosophy. Or to change the metaphor, they make up a kind of triptych. We are apter to keep things separate. Moreover, the three comprise a philosophy of Absolute Idealism which, for good reasons and bad, is held by few philosophers nowadays and even fewer symbolic logicians.

If for this reason Hegel does not offer a logic which squares with modern logic, he also repudiates the traditional Aristotelian logic and its Scholastic outgrowths. Logicians who are sympathetic to this traditional logic find little of relevance to them in Hegel's logic. Hegel falls between two stools of ancient and modern.

You still want to read Hegel ?

Hegel's *Encyclopaedia of the Philosophical Sciences* covers logic, nature, and spirit ('mind') in a relatively accessible way - relative, that is, to his *Science of Logic* and *Phenomenology of Spirit*. You can pick up logic, metaphysics and epistemology from all three. The part on logic, usually called *The Lesser Logic*, is probably the most accessible if you're new to Hegel.

---

References

G.W.F. Hegel, The Encyclopaedia Logic, G. W. F. Hegel, T. F. Geraets (translator), W. A. Suchting (translator), H. S. Harris (translator). ISBN 10: 0872200701 / ISBN 13: 9780872200708
Published by Hackett Publishing Company 1991-10-15, Indianapolis, 1991.

Online :

https://rosswolfe.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/georg-wilhelm-friedrich-hegel-encyclopedia-logic.pdf

Justus Hartnack, An Introduction to Hegel's Logic (Hackett Classics Series). ISBN 10: 0872204243 / ISBN 13: 9780872204249
Published by Hackett Publishing Company, Inc.,1998.

Comment: 'no other concept can be more adequate to reality' why isn't this a "proposition"

Comment: @user3293056 it isn't formal proposition, which is what I take out to be the main different between Hegel's Era of logic and contemporary logic.

Comment: Hi GT, I would love to ask though as a sort of minor follow up question, is the sort of interwoven logic-metaphysics-epistemology that Hegel (and, as far as I understand it, Kant and Decartes) use have any relevance to contemporary philosophy?

Comment: @Yechiam Weiss. Hello again ! I think it does but more in French & German philosophy than in the Anglo-American analytical tradition. Badieu, Ricoeur, and of course Heidegger.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas right, the analytical-continental distinction. I wonder if it still applies to today's academic philosophy, as from what I've heard there's been a lot of influence between both sides and now there are "analytical" philosophers that'd consider themselves "continental", and vice versa.

Comment: @Yechiam Weiss. Yes, there is far more interest by each 'side' in the other than was the case, say, in the 1950s. But the rift has not closed. For every US or UK philosopher who rates Heidegger highly there are a dozen who dismiss him as an empty obscurantist. (Not my view.) Also relatively few Anglo-American philosophers are familiar with the work of Gadamer, Sartre, beside the other names I mentioned. They've heard the names but don't read the books. A test : take any introductory A/A text on logic, epistemology, metaphysics, and see how many Continental names appear in the Bibliography. GT

Comment: Current or recent Continental names, I mean - not Descartes, Leibniz or Kant.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas that's most probably true, unfortunately. I sincerely can't comprehend how so many philosopher can allow themselves to simply ignore a whole "tradition" (though even calling it a tradition is staying in Russell's distinction). But alas, unfortunately we can't make this comment section into a conversation chat, although this topic is very interesting to me and I'd love to chat about it.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Well, Girard, the creator of [linear logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic), claims that his formalism vindicates "*Hegel's contradictory foundations*", and that his colleagues misinterpret Hegel by taking his negation as alethic rather than game-theoretic. His semantic programme is called ["transcendental syntax"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8548/a157279b27de84d1effd772b683c7b9d7701.pdf), and yes, Kant is his even greater inspiration. I have to say that analytic logicians are not at all innocent of mixing logic with metaphysics, take Lewis, Kripke or Williamson.

Comment: I agree : I don't believe you can do any part of philosophy without making assumptions about, or carrying implications for, other areas of the subject. I am not familiar with Girard's work but a game-theoretic reading of Hegel is more creative than convincing. However, I speak in ignorance of G's work. Best - G

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - In my view the sort of interwoven logic-metaphysics-epistemology that Hegel uses is vital to philosophy at any time and place. I cannot see how they can be studied in isolation and predict that any attempt to do so will be fruitless.

Answer (score 3):

Hegel's logic lies almost completely in the part of logic that modern logicians no longer study -- how discovery and the evolution of ideas work as a process, rather than as a set of rules.

It has also been rolled up into systems that we wish to disown as science and which modern science has decided are unlikely to discover anything or evolve.  Excluding the materialist offspring of Hegel's logic is what motivated Popper to try to define the boundary around the sciences.  And the sciences themselves have largely accepted his demarcation criterion in the work they do to police themselves.

So you will seldom find modern logicians that engage this theory at all.  Since the advent of the modern analytic approach in the 'linguistic turn' things like motivation and evolution of a train of thought, like dialectic, are not logic anymore.  They are considered something closer to politics or rational psychology.

Rational psychology has been largely displaced by concerns about science, since modernism set in, and the philosophical discipline of politics has become sociology.

Comment: I wonder why this has been downvoted? Ideally it would have references but it's def accurate.

Comment: I upvoted it. Russell himself led the charge against Hegel, and he had some fun with Hegel's logic. (Russell had studied Hegel early on and he was a "fan".). But Russell was also a socialist, according to his archivist, which is no surprise to me. Kenneth Blackwell, The Spinozistic Ethics of Bertrand Russell.

Comment: What I am saying is that Rusell was perfectly capable of keeping another logic, like Hegel's "logic", in the background.

Comment: Walter Kaufmann (Philosopher and Translator of Popper) on Popper's Hegel. https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/us/kaufmann.htm

Comment: @Canyon it wasn't me, though i found it frustrating that the answer was "they don't" and that could have been made clearer for a quick reader

Comment: Jobermark is closer to a mainstream view, widely held, and I see no need to downvote it. Popper was a very convenient fellow, but even Adorno and Horkheimer were enticed into a convenient arrangement after WW II.

Comment: @Gordon like i said "they don't" followed by "the mainstream view" without being "clear" could rile. i'm not saying it's a bad answer, but it could use some "references". what's not to get?

Comment: @user3293056 I never did think you downvoted it.

Comment: @Gordon ok. cool

Comment: @ everyone freak out about a down vote, I down voted this answer for the same reason I always do when I do down vote an answer by jobermark, the answer contains no citations, there are a lot of conjectures which, even if they are true, are still conjectures with no appeal to any sort of argument, and because it's handwavy. "So you will seldom find modern logicians that engage this theory at all.", this is the perfect example. "You will seldom find", well, that means sometimes you will find it, and the OP asked for examples, so why phrase what you're saying this way? It's a lazy answer.

Comment: Jobermark makes these answers all the time, that's fine, they are going to continue to do so. I am not here to argue with them about what they should or shouldn't post as an answer, I am here to explain to the people who are freaking out that someone down voted this, just so we're clear about intentions. I am not here to start an argument about the quality of the answer, especially since I know I won't win and the answers will continue to be posted.

Comment: To the Kaufmann link: "the materialist offspring of Hegel's logic" does not mean Hegel.  There is no reference here to what Popper said of Hegel's politics.  To the complaint about 'they don't' not being obvious -- it is in the first sentence.  Some tiny part of some few logicians; work does include this kind of stuff -- the thread that led to the Roman subject of 'rhetoric proper' unrelated to artistry.  So the two word answer would be false, and this is not.

Answer (score 2):

Within the realm of propositional calculus, there was an attempt to formalize Hegel's way of thinking by a four-valued logic called "directional logic" by a Polish logician L. Rogowski. Unfortunately, his two papers containing that idea were published in journals which no longer exist.

1. L. S. Rogowski,"The logical sense of Hegel’s concept of change andmovement (in Polish) Studia Filozoficzne no. 6 (27), pp. 3–39.
2. L. S. Rogowski, "Directional logic and Hegel’s thesis on the contradict of change", Prace Wydziału Filologiczno-Filozoficznego TNT, vol. 15 no. 2, pp. 5–32.

Regards, Maciej Janowicz

Answer (score 0):

I only know of one mathematician who engaged seriously with Hegel---William Lawvere, in, for instance, his paper on [the unity of opposites in physics](https://github.com/mattearnshaw/lawvere/blob/master/pdfs/1996-unity-and-identity-of-opposites-in-calculus-and-physics.pdf). I can't say if it's correct, because I don't understand nearly enough category theory, and, of course, I don't understand Hegel.

Lawvere's work has inspired at least one further attempt to model Hegel in category theory: [this absolutely insane formalization of the *Science of Logic*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Science+of+Logic). Again, I can't make too much of it, because I don't understand category theory. But since it starts at a more fundamental level it was possible to follow along at least a bit, and that bit seemed superficially correct.

And yet I don't recommend treating Hegel with the tools of modern logic. The above formalization seems to me to do incredible violence to Hegel's ideas. Some comments in the *Lesser Logic*, section 19, addition 2, shed light on his view:

> Anybody can think, it is believed, without the study of logic, much as one can digest food without having studied physiology. And even if one has studied logic, one thinks just as one did before, perhaps more methodically, but otherwise with little difference, or so it seems. If logic had no other business than to familiarize us with the activity of merely formal thinking, then it would indeed produce nothing one would not have otherwise been doing just as well all along. The earlier logic was in fact reduced to this position.

Mathematical logic, it seems to me, can only ever "familiarize us with the activity of merely formal thinking". The truly essential *philosophical* elements are all already presupposed in the form of axioms and rules of inference. Hegel appears to want to change the way we think, not merely formalize it. So logic, as we conceive of it nowadays, has very little to do with Hegel's project. It's not surprising, then, that there's so little formal logical work on Hegel.

Answer (score 0):

Lenin said one must understand Hegel's Science of Logic to understand Marxism, but many doubt that he understood it at all. Kierkegaard admitted that he did not understand much of Hegel, but comforted himself that "neither did Hegel."

With a few exceptions, as noted by others, there is really very little overlap between modern logic and Hegel's system. In the the Kneale's 800-page tome "The Development of Logic," from Pythagoras to Godel, Hegel's name does not appear even once in the index.

I have a good companion book to "Phenomenology of Spirit" entitled "The Logic of Desire," and this is not a bad description of what Hegel is up to. He employs the thinking process we might call Logos, dialectic, or syllogism in a way that includes embodiment, purposes, desires, and, importantly, history. While formalisms like math or logic strive to be abstract, universal, and "timeless," Hegel sees "Logic" as a living teleological process that reflects on its own history. Ideas like "truth" or "justice" are thus historically contingent, yet undergo a continuous self-reflective development.

This process is true in the individual mind, in the development of philosophy as self-reflection, and in history itself. Because contradictions are both synthesized and preserved within the new synthesis "the identity of difference and identity" Hegel is far from the "either-or" distinctions employed in analytical logic. Distinctions collapse into one another in an evolutionary continuum. Generally, the murky, topsy-turvy development of his reasoning drives "logical" people crazy!

Definitely a slog. But Hegel is well worth studying and especially alongside Marx. As noted, the "Lesser Logic" is probably best, and some people think his early theological writings give you a good introduction to his dialectical "trinitarian" way of proceeding. "Phenomenology of Spirit," his most famous work, is supposed to be an introduction to his logic, but one can hardly call it "clarifying" or "introductory." While he was once totally excluded from the curriculum, he has returned to favor and there are many good companion books, including the famous lectures by Alexandre Kojeve that stirred up a Hegel revival.